# assert() in nested function

Tags: solidity, blockchain

What will happen if I use **assert()** inside the **function inside()** which is called from the **function main()** ?
If condition is **true** then control returns to *function main()* .  What if condition is **false**? Do it return back to *function main()* or  **exit** from the contract execution ?
As far as I know if the condition is *false* then It **throws**. This **throws** *exit the function* or exit the *contract execution* ?

```
function inside(){  
      assert(x>y);  

  }  
  function main(){  
      inside();  

  }
```

Comment: Sharing some code would help us understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short : the function assert(bool condition) : throws if the condition is not met.thus in your code if the condition is false the inside function will throw and stop the contract execution.